# Populate HTML Table with Array and Create Links

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a site that will have pages for various countries and regions. On a main page I'm looking to populate an HTML table that is 4 columns by 12 rows (48 results) from an array. I current have a loop working that is placing each country into it's own paragraph but I'm lost on how to place them into the table and have them setup in the 4x12 way I described above.

Here is the query:

```
$country_sql = "SELECT * FROM country";
$country_query = mysql_query($country_sql) or die(mysql_error());
$rsCountry = mysql_fetch_assoc($country_query);
```

Then within the page I have this working right now that inserts each country into a new paragraph:

```
<?php do {?>
<p><?php echo $rsCountry['countryname'];?></p>
<?php } while ($rsCountry = mysql_fetch_assoc($country_query)) ?>
```

First I need to have this place data into seperate td's instead of new paragraphs. Once I have this data in a table I then need the country names link to each countries respective page which is setup as mydomain.com/country/countryabbreviation (countryabbreviation is within the same table as countryname). Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I'm very new to php. Thanks!

----Full Code---

```
<?php
///CONNECTION INFORMATION REMOVED FOR PRIVACY//////////


$country_sql = "SELECT * FROM country";
$country_query = mysql_query($country_sql) or die(mysql_error());
$rsCountry = mysql_fetch_assoc($country_query);

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" content="text/html">
    <title>TEST PAGE </title> 
</head>

<body>

<h1>List of Countries</h1>
<?php do {?>
<p><?php echo $rsCountry['countryname'];?></a></p>
<?php } while ($rsCountry = mysql_fetch_assoc($country_query)) ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Outputs this:
http://postimg.org/image/f2muo627d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php

// Rewrote the query to only get 48 items.
$country_sql = "SELECT * FROM country LIMIT 48";
$country_query = mysql_query($country_sql) or die(mysql_error());

// Initialize an empty array.
$rsCountry = array();

// Put all our countries in there.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($country_query)) {
  $item = array();
  $item['href'] = '/country/' . $row['countryabbreviation'];
  $item['title'] = $row['countryname'];
  $rsCountry[] = $item;
}

// Chop up our massive array in rows of 4, should give us 12 rows.
$rsCountry = array_chunk($rsCountry, 4);

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" content="text/html">
    <title>TEST PAGE</title> 
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <h1>List of Countries</h1>    
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><?php
      foreach ($rsCountry as $row => $countries): ?>
      <tr><?php
        foreach ($countries as $country): ?>
        <td><a href="<?= $country['href'] ?>"><?= echo $country['title'] ?></a></td><?php
        endforeach; ?>
      </tr><?php
      endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I forgot about the linking the countries to their pages part, but I will update the answer soon to incorporate that.

Comment: Kristian, awesome man that did the trick. I got the links working on my end. Much appreciated :-)

Comment: Your welcome. I did add the rest of the answer ;) but glad you were able to figure that out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want? I didn't test if it compiles

```
   $country_sql = "SELECT * FROM country";
   $country_query = mysql_query($country_sql) or die(mysql_error());
   $rsCountry = mysql_fetch_array($country_query)
   echo "<table><th>";
   $firstrow ="";
   foreach( $rsCountry as $name => $cell ){
       echo "<td>$name</td>";
       $firstrow = $firstrow + "<td>$cell</td>";
   }
   echo "</th>";
   echo "<tr>$firsrow</tr>";
   while( $rsCountry = mysql_fetch_array($country_query) ){
       echo "<tr>";
       foreach( $rsCountry as $cell ){
           echo "<td>$cell</td>";
       }
       echo "</tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
```

Comment: not sure why but this doesn't work at all for me, when I add your code i get a blank page (added between <?php ?>)

Comment: did you first fetch this $country_sql = "SELECT * FROM country";
$country_query = mysql_query($country_sql) or die(mysql_error());
$rsCountry = mysql_fetch_assoc($country_query);

could you describe more precisely how the result of $country_sql = "SELECT * FROM country" looks?

Comment: yes I did, i just added it to my page that worked previously, i'ved edited above to show the whole page

Comment: edited my post, I cannot test it right now. I don't have enough info about the table to be sure it works either